# Header above UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, header, uinavigationbar

My iOS application currently is using an `UINavigationController`  but I need to add a custom header above the navigation bar.

It should be something similar to this: [Calcio app](http://itunes.apple.com/it/app/vodafone-calcio/id342886317?mt=8)

How can this be developed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your UINavigationController's view inside another UIView.

By default your rootViewController's view is added to a window in your application delegate.

At the application delegate level,create another UIView or UIViewController that manages both the UINavigationController's view, and some other view that displays what ever it is you want displayed above the UINavigationBar.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I got it. Please would you kindly suggest a piece of code with what you proposed?